# Update in C# using Access database

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ms-access

I've been trying to update in a DataGridView and it keeps returning this

> No value given for one or more required parameters

Here's my code

```
private void btnAlterar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    try
    {
        string strincon = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\flavi\Desktop\Pet&Shop.2\PetShop\TelaAbertura\bin\Debug\DatabasePS.mdb;Persist Security Info=True";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strincon);
        con.Open();

        String comando = "UPDATE Funcionario SET Nome= '" + txtNome.Text + "' , Login= '" + txtLogin.Text + "' , Senha= '" + txtSenha.Text + "', Email= '" + txtEmail.Text + "' , Cargo= '" + txtCargo.Text + "' WHERE Codigo =" + codigo;

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(comando, con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Dados Alterados Com Sucesso!");

        txtCargo.Clear();
        txtEmail.Clear();
        txtLogin.Clear();
        txtNome.Clear();
        txtSenha.Clear();

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual SQL code that you're trying to execute which produces this error?  (The runtime value of `comando`)

Comment: I can do the Select*From Funcionario to consult the datas, and now I want to be able to update them

Comment: Indeed.  And you appear to be encountering an error while attempting to do so.  I assume that's what you're asking about, yes?  The error you've described indicates that the database engine is expecting parameters in the SQL code you're executing, but no parameters are provided.  So... What is the SQL code you are executing?  The C# code you're showing dynamically builds SQL code based on runtime input (which is very unsafe and highly error prone, by the way... you should take a look at parameterized queries).  So currently we don't know what your SQL code is.  Can you show us?

Comment: Double check your column names in the database, when Access sees something that doesn't match up, it thinks you're including a parameter without giving it a value. You could probably eliminate a lot of this by using parameterized statements btw.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add brackets on field names because may be some field name is keyword on Access. Change your query as follow:

```
String comando = "UPDATE [Funcionario] SET [Nome]= '" + txtNome.Text + "' , [Login]= '" + txtLogin.Text + "' , [Senha]= '" + txtSenha.Text + "', [Email]= '" + txtEmail.Text + "' , [Cargo]= '" + txtCargo.Text + "' WHERE [Codigo] =" + codigo;
```

Comment: Try using `parameters` instead of concatenation of string this certainly solves your problem . But your problem may be related to `quotation mark`. Check that there is no `quotation mark` in values of textBoxes.